# Design / Architecture for many instances OOP (or another) implementation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

We want to write an API (Python Library) which provides information about few systems in our company. **We really aren't sure what is the best OOP approach to implement what we want, so I hope you'll have an idea.**

The API will expose a series of tests for each system. Each system will be presented as a Class (with properties and methods) and all systems will inherit from a base class (GenericSystem) which will contain basic, generic info regarding the system (I.E dateOfCreation, authors, systemType, name, technology, owner, etc.) Each system has many instances and each instance has a unique ID. Data about each system instance is stored in different databases, so the API will be a place where all users can find info regarding those systems at once. These are the requirements:

1. We want each user to be able to create an instance of a system (SystemName Class for example) and to be able to get some info about it.
2. We want each user to be able to create multiple instances of a system (or of GenericSystem) and to be able to get info about all of them at once. (It must be efficient. One query only, not one for each instance). So we thought that we may need to create MultipleSystemNames class which will implement all those plural-approach methods. **This is the most challenging requirement, as it seems.**
3. We want that data will be populated and cached to the instances properties and methods. So if I create a SystemName instance and calls systemNameInstance.propertyName, it will run needed queries and populate the data into propertyName. Next time the user will call this property, the data will be immediately returned.
4. Last one, **a single system class approach must be preserved**. Each system must be presented as a sole system. We can later create MultiSystem class if needed (For requirement 2) but at it's most basic form, each system must be represented singly (I hope you understand what I mean).

The second and the fourth (2,4) requirements are the ones that we really struggle to figure out.
Should we use MultiSystemNames class for each class and also for GenericSystem (MultiGenericSystems)? We don't want to complicate the user and ourselves.

Do you know any OOP (or another) best practice clean and simplified way? Have we missed something? 
I'm sorry if I added some unnecessary information but I really wanted to give you a feel about how we want things to be.

If you've reach so far or not, thank you!

Comment: Can you eager-load all data for a single system or you only want to load what's requested only? I'm not sure I like the proxy approach.

Comment: Quite broad, how many users, how much data from your systems, how do the users interact with the system. 1 user or 10,000 users would make a huge difference to how you model and code it.

Comment: @plalx I want to load what is requested only. Each instance will be first loaded with basic info which being queried to validate the instance’s id.

Comment: @Matthew Page As I said, users will use this as a python library (we might also export a web api which user will be able to accesss to through http. We predict around 100 users from within our company which will use our api to build their systems also. All databases already exist. Each system is already built, we only need to unite the data into one place.

Answer (score 0):

System and instance represents exactly the same think but are used in different contexts. It doesn't matter how you store or retrieve them. So if you need a collection of System you just use native collection data structure (e.g List, Queue, Map in java). The operations related to System/List must be decoupled from POJOs. That means you implement them in services, repositories,etc.
How you store and retrieve the data must not have impact on how you design your data structures. You achieve performance by applying different techniques and/or using proper technologies e.g caching, using key-value stores or nosql databases, denormalize relational database tables and/or using indexes,etc

Comment: Well, all systems are already built, all databases are already created and systems are flowing data into them. Systems are using different data stores. SQL Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL, windows shares, AWSS3, Elasticsearch and DynamoDB. The api should use all these existing databases and cannot change any structure...

Comment: If everything is already in place, implement a thin decoration layer for aggregating the different systems. The layer will be the API. This way data retrieval can be optimized for each system, caching can be added transparently and semantics can be added, data enriched etc.